# How can I update my API created in symfony from React?

Tags: reactjs, symfony

I have created an API in symfony to consume it in React. How can I add more data to the API from React?

I have only managed to add data through phpMyAdmin. I don't know if there is a way to create a form in react to be able to update the data from there, from the web deployed. The entire project is local.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller that persists the info sent to it by the front. Example:

```
$email = $request->query->get("email");
$user->setEmail($email);
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

You can send the info to controller through the PATCH method. Yo can make a API with this method

```
GET
/api/users
Retrieves the collection of Users resources.
POST
/api/user
Creates a User resource.
GET
/api/users/{id}
Retrieves a User resource.
PUT
/api/users/{id}
Replaces the User resource.
DELETE
/api/users/{id}
Removes the User resource.
PATCH
/api/users/{id}
Updates the User resource.
```